# why isn't symfony2 doctrine applying lifecycle callback when I use annotations on document file

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm trying to put the code that basically stores the date a document was created on the same document file (I've seen many tutorials that registers a listener in the services.xml file etc.. i don't want that.. I want all the code to be on the same page).

So basically my document file is called Driver.php.. This is the code I'm using:

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="St\AppBundle\Repository\DriverRepository", requireIndexes=true)
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Driver
{
  .. 

    /**
     * @MongoDB\int
     * @MongoDB\Index
     */
    protected $createdAt;


    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param int $createdAt
     * @return Driver
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return int $createdAt
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    .. 

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function storeDateCrated()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: try removing `()` from where exactly?

Comment: Of `HasLifecycleCallbacks`. Maybe it is irrelevant, but I never met with this annotation using `()`. In docs they arent there too.

Comment: did you mean `HasLifecycleCallbacks`? yeah just tried that.. no good

Comment: maybe do you have to clear the cache

Comment: @skler tried that as well

Comment: Never had any experience with `ODM` but I find it really unlikely for `ORM` annotation to be used with `ODM`, don't you?

Comment: @jperovic i'm afraid you are right.. see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is all what I had to do:

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\PrePersist
 */
public function storeDateCrated()
{
    $date=  new \DateTime();
    $this->createdAt = $date->getTimestamp();
}
```

and I removed this line

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

although this isn't really related.. this code is based on a project i inherited (from symfony experts.. i don't know squat about symfony).. the thing is when i searched the entire code base for `PrePersist` I got nothing.. but then i searched for that term on *all* previous commits by running

```
git log -SPreCommit // general way: git log -Sword when searching for "word"
```

this gave me a list of all commit hashes that had used preCommit in them.. I openend up one of the commits and found that this syntax was used.. and voila!

Answer (score 1):

You were using DoctrineORM's annotation. That works only for relational databases such as MySql, postgreSql. Instead use this:

```
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\HasLifecycleCallbacks;

/**
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
 class Driver
 {
```